# Multi page Tiff files in FME

Tags: fme-form, geotiff-tiff

I have a workbench which returns multi page .Tiff files as xml then outputs back to Tiff.

I use the XML Flattener, TextDecoder and RasterReplacer transformers to decode and rasterize the images. I then write to Tif but the writer only returns the first page of the multi page Tif.

Any ideas on how to return all of the pages?

Below is a screenshot of the process. I'm thinking it could be something to do with the RasterReplacer not populating the tiff_subdataset_name' which delineates a multi page Tiff file.

[image]

Comment: call imagemagick command-line with convert multipage.tif single%d.tif you can edit this FME Hub Tranformer tool (change gifs to tifs)  to do this https://hub.safe.com/transformers/animatedgifwriter